# Create an Excel Macro to categorize data based on values (by writing data to a cell based on the value in another cell.)

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm completely at a loss for complex excel tasks, but I'm facing the following situation.
I've got a large list of inventory items with various lengths, but I need to convert the exact lengths (as a numerical value) into a categorical value (i.e. between 10-15, between 16-20, etc).

All of the length data is in a single column, and I'd like to write the data to a second column.

I could create a complex, cascading if-then formula - but my understanding is that this would be very taxing on the system and it is also not an all an efficient way to go about doing this.

Can someone provide some guidance?  I'm using Excel 2013, in case that makes a difference for syntax.

Edit:The specific categories I have are as follows (in feet, but just the number is fine).
10-15, 16-20, 21-25, 26-30, 31-40, 41+

I'd also like to have an N/A category for invalid entries (i.e. no data entered).  All data will be whole numbers.

Comment: Are the categories systematic e.g. always in groups of 5?  I note that's not how your example goes.

Comment: That's a valid question.  No, not always.  I was hoping that I'd be able to specify the values for each category along with the "category text for each one."  However, I'll edit my question with the exact specifics I need for categories.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Pivot Add-In to address this.

I would load the inventory data and a banding table into Power Pivot.  The Power Pivot CALCULATE function can make light work of complex table relationships like that.

Here's a good example, from a site which has a ton of other Power Pivot content if this is new to you:

http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2012/04/aged-debtorsdynamic-banding-in-dax/